# How do I draw an abstract graph as in the picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to draw a directed graph like the one below, but simpler:

[image]

This is my current code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 [    
 roundnode/.style={circle, draw=black, fill=black, thin, minimum size=0.5mm},
 ]

 \node[roundnode]        (node1)        {};

 \node[roundnode]        (node2)       [right=of node1] {};

 \draw[->] (node1.east) -- (node2.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but I'm struggling to get the vertices as small as in the picture, and I don't know how to get the labels outside of the vertices.

Comment: If you know Python, you can check [sane_tikz](https://github.com/negrinho/sane_tikz). Here is a similar example to what you want: [output](https://github.com/negrinho/sane_tikz/blob/master/examples/pentagon.pdf), [python code](https://github.com/negrinho/sane_tikz/blob/master/examples/pentagon.py), [generated tex code](https://github.com/negrinho/sane_tikz/blob/master/examples/pentagon.tex).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt]
\newcommand{\vertex}{\node[vertex]}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\vertex (a) at (30:1) [label=right:$5$]{};
\vertex (a1) at (90:1) [label=above:$1$]{};
\vertex (a2) at (150:1) [label=left:$2$]{};
\vertex (a3) at (210:.7) [label=below:$3$]{};
\vertex (a4) at (330:.7) [label=below:$4$]{};
\path [->,>=latex,shorten >=0.2]
(a1) edge node[above]{D} (a2)
(a) edge (a1)
(a) edge (a3)
(a1) edge (a3)
(a1) edge (a4)
(a2) edge (a)
(a2) edge (a3)
(a2) edge (a4)
(a4) edge (a3)
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**Edit2**: code above

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[vertex/.style={circle,fill,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt}]
\node [vertex] (a) at (30:1) [label=right:$5$]{};
\node [vertex] (a1) at (90:1) [label=above:$1$]{};
\node [vertex] (a2) at (150:1) [label=left:$2$]{};
\node [vertex] (a3) at (210:.7) [label=below:$3$]{};
\node [vertex] (a4) at (330:.7) [label=below:$4$]{};
\path [->,>=latex,shorten >=0.2]
(a1) edge node[above]{D} (a2)
(a) edge (a1)
(a) edge (a3)
(a1) edge (a3)
(a1) edge (a4)
(a2) edge (a)
(a2) edge (a3)
(a2) edge (a4)
(a4) edge (a3)
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Edit1:

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[Ahmadi/.style={circle,fill,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt}]
\node [Ahmadi](b) at (0,0) {};
\node [Ahmadi](b1) at (1,0) {};
\node [Ahmadi](b4) at (3.5,0) {};
\node (b2) at (2,0)[right]{$\dots$};
\node (b3) at (2.5,0){};

\path [->,>=latex,shorten >=0.1]
(b) edge (b1)
(b1) edge (b2)
(b3) edge (b4)
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

output

[image]

Comment: What does ```(30:1)``` mean? In particular, how could I play around with the positioning to get graphs in a different shape? Also, could you tell me if it's possible to have ellipses in a graph, like the following: https://imgur.com/tsR74Ls

Comment: (30:1) 30 Angle and 1 the length. See edit

Comment: Please note the `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat  Thanks. Edited

Answer (score 4):

You can do such things with some graph drawing libraries but this is very simple so that you can do it easily without libraries.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path[every edge/.style={-latex,thick,draw}] foreach \X in {1,...,5}
  {(18+\X*72:1.2) node[circle,inner
  sep=1.5pt,fill,label={[anchor=18+\X*72+180]18+\X*72:\X}](p\X){}}
  (p1) edge (p2) edge (p3) edge (p4) 
  (p2) edge (p3) edge (p4) edge (p5)  
  (p5) edge (p1) edge (p3) 
  (p4) edge (p3)
  (126:1.4) node{$D$} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.very good .+1

Answer (score 1):

The Ti*k*Z package is *very* powerful, and comes with an array of libraries for lots of uses. The other answers show forms of drawing your specific graph. For more details on such drawings, check out Crémers ["Minimal Ti*k*Z"](https://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf). There is an impressive [gallery](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples).

Another alternative is to use e.g. [Graphviz](http://graphviz.org/), a program that offers lots of ways of drawing graphs, even automatic layouts for large ones. It is an external set of programs, however.